# LLVM build: source duplicated from a working build

Tags: makefile, cmake, llvm

I am trying to build a LLVM from a working copy I have from another machine. The original source is build using `configure` and `make`. However, on the new systems the same build method fails (I have tried `make clean`). I tried the `cmake` option and it says the following:

Basically there seems to be some left over files from the earlier build, so the question is how do I remove it, elegantly, i.e not with a linux command but using the LLVM build system itself. `make distclean` says "No rule to make target `disctclean'.  Stop."

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 6.0.0.6000056
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 6.0.0.6000056
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:57 (message):
  Apparently there is a previous in-source build,

  probably as the result of running `configure' and `make' on

  /Users/me/scp/llvm_release.

  This may cause problems.  The suspicious files are: 
/Users/me/scp/llvm_release/lib/Target/AArch64/AArch64GenAsmWriter.inc;
...
...
/Users/me/scp/llvm_release/lib/Target/XCore/XCoreGenSubtargetInfo.inc
/Users/me/scp/llvm_release/include/llvm/IR/Intrinsics.gen

 Please clean the source directory.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 1):

The LLVM build system does not provide a solution for this problem. You can start from scratch with clean sources or use some linux shell voodoo to get rid of all `.gen` files.

Answer (score 0):

This is one reason why we use a separate build directory in the directions here:

http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary

The easiest way would be to restart with a clean set of source and avoid using configure and make in the source directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked the source out using source control you can just use that to remove all the untracked files and reset all the modified ones.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the mentioned files:

```
Users/me/scp/llvm_release/lib/Target/AArch64/AArch64GenAsmWriter.inc;
...
...
/Users/me/scp/llvm_release/lib/Target/XCore/XCoreGenSubtargetInfo.inc
/Users/me/scp/llvm_release/include/llvm/IR/Intrinsics.gen
```

and then run run make or cmake or ninja again. If it complains that a file is missing then copy the missing file from the original LLVM source code.